# Calculating random number in ECDSA based on private key and signature

Tags: signature, dsa

In [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) we use a random number $k$ in the signature process.

Signature in ECDSA is:

$$ (x_1,y_1) = [k]G $$
$$r = x_1 \bmod n $$
$$s = k^{-1} (z+r\,d_{a}) \bmod n$$

If we know the private key $d_a$ and signature $(r,s)$ would it be possible to calculate random $k$? If not how hard would it be to calculate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is immediate:
$$ k = s^{-1} (z + r \, d_a) \bmod n $$
where $z$ is the hash value of the message being signed.